# Origin of the Hankel contour?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

Who was the first to publish a Hankel contour integral?

See notes in my answer to the MO-Q  [How does one motivate the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58004/how-does-one-motivate-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/97401#97401).